# How can I detect multiple logins into a Django web application from different locations?

Tags: django, django-authentication

I want to only allow one authenticated session at a time for an individual login in my Django application.  So if a user is logged into the webpage on a given IP address, and those same user credentials are used to login from a different IP address I want to do something (either logout the first user or deny access to the second user.)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Not sure if this is still needed but thought I would share my solution:

1) Install django-tracking (thankyou for that tip Van Gale Google Maps + GeoIP is amazing!)

2) Add this middleware:

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
from tracking.models import Visitor
from datetime import datetime

class UserRestrictMiddleware(object):
    """
    Prevents more than one user logging in at once from two different IPs
    """
    def process_request(self, request):
        ip_address = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR','')
        try:
            last_login = request.user.last_login
        except:
            last_login = 0
        if unicode(last_login)==unicode(datetime.now())[:19]:
            previous_visitors = Visitor.objects.filter(user=request.user).exclude(ip_address=ip_address)
            for visitor in previous_visitors:
                Session.objects.filter(session_key=visitor.session_key).delete()
                visitor.user = None
                visitor.save()
```

3) Make sure it goes after the VisitorTrackingMiddleware and you should find previous logins are automatically bumped when someone new logs in :)

Comment: Can we trust django-tracking after all these years of inactivity?

Answer (score 10):

If you're already using django-tracking as suggested here, there's a much easier way to implement this:

Define a signal handler:

```
# myapp/signals.py
def kick_my_other_sessions(sender, request=None, user=None, **kwargs):
    from tracking.models import Visitor
    from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
    keys = [v.session_key for v in Visitor.objects.filter(user=request.user).exclude(session_key=request.session.session_key)]
    Session.objects.filter(session_key__in=keys).delete()
```

Create a listener for the user_logged_in signal:

```
# myapp/__init__.py
from myapp.signals import kick_my_other_sessions
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in
user_logged_in.connect(kick_my_other_sessions, sender=User)
```

This will institute a sort of "last user to login wins" system.  If you want to allow multiple logins by the same user from the same ip, you can add an `.exclude()` to the `Visitors` lookup.

Comment: It is useful to also set `visitor.user = None` for each of the matched visitors otherwise this code will still find visitors for already deleted sessions on every login. (This matters if you decide to add a message to tell the newly logged in user 'you have just been logged out of another session').

Answer (score 7):

Django's [middleware](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#topics-http-middleware) will probably help you achieve this. The issue is that you will probably want to allow multiple anonymous sessions from the same IP address, even authenticated sessions for different users, but not authenticated sessions for the same user.

You'll want to:

1. Create a user profile model to store the IP address of a user's last login. See Django's [Storing additional information about users](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) documentation.
2. Implement a [custom authentication backend](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#writing-an-authentication-backend). This backend, when triggered and successfully authenticating a user (just call super) would wipe out the user's last login IP in the profile model.
3. Implement a subclass of Django's `django.contrib.sessions.SessionMiddleware` class. Implement `process_request`. If the `request.user` object's profile model has no IP address, set it and allow the request. If it has an IP, and the IP is different from the current request's IP (`request.META.REMOTE_ADDR`), then do whatever you like to either log out the other user, or return an error to the requestor.
4. Update your `settings.py` file so that your custom auth backend is processed first, and so that your custom session middleware is also processed first. This involves updating `settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` and `settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`.

Comment: If you only restrict by IP, then it's possible that a user would share his/her login within a company, and they'd come from the same source address due to IP masquerading. So for some use-cases this is not strict enough to prevent multi-usages

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to do this with custom middleware.

In your middleware `process_request()` method you will have access to the request object so you can do something like the following:

```
session_key = request.session.session_key
ip_address = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR', '')
```

Now you know the IP address, so check a model you create that (roughly) would look like this:

```
class SessionIPS(models.Model):
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session)
    IP = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

So when a session is created or deleted you will modifiy your session ip's table accordingly, and when a request comes in make sure the IP address isn't being used for another session.  If if is, then return a Http404 (or something like it) from the middleware.

A pluggable app that can show  you a lot more detail (and even includes IP address in its own model) is [django-tracking](http://code.google.com/p/django-tracking/).