# Django signals on GAE with django-nonrel

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I am using django-nonrel for my project on GAE. My requirement is that in my application at a time only one user should login with the given username. I tried to implement the following suggested approaches: 
[Allow only one concurrent login per user in django app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814437/allow-only-one-concurrent-login-per-user-in-django-app) and [How can I detect multiple logins into a Django web application from different locations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821870/how-can-i-detect-multiple-logins-into-a-django-web-application-from-different-loc) 
But the problem is that both of the approaches working on the development server but didn't work on google app engine. So I switched to django-signals as my alternate approach. I created one post_login signal which will store the username for every login user in a table Visitor in database. On every logout,other signal post_logout will remove the user from this table.The part of codes are as:

```
#signals.py
post_login = django.dispatch.Signal(providing_args=['request', 'user'])
post_logout = django.dispatch.Signal(providing_args=['request', 'user'])
#models.py
def login_handler(sender,user, **kwargs):
    try:
        result=Visitor.objects.get(user=user)
        print "You already have login with your name"
    except:
        visitor=Visitor()
        visitor.user=user
        visitor.save()
post_login.connect(login_handler)


def logout_handler(sender,user, **kwargs):
    try:
        result=Visitor.objects.get(user=user)
        result.delete()
    except:
        return False
post_logout.connect(logout_handler)

#django.contrib.auth.__init.py__
def login(request):
 :
 user_logged_in.send(sender=user.__class__, request=request, user=user)
  post_login.send(sender=None,request=request, user=user)

def logout(request):
:
user_logged_out.send(sender=user.__class__, request=request, user=user)
post_logout.send(sender=None,request=request, user=user)
```

Please note that I am getting the following error while running my application on google app engine.
Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.

Also I am not able to login into Admin part of the application. Please help me to find right approach to implement this requirement or let me know where I am doing wrong.
Thanks for your patience for reading this huge problem description :-)

Comment: "Error: Server Error" is not an error message; it's the default web page returned for a 500 error.  Check the logs for your application and paste a traceback, or at least the actual error message.

Comment: @Wooble:Thanks Wooble for your response..actually I don't know where to check logs or actual error message on google app engine..what do I need to do for this ?

Comment: @Wooble: I hope I need to use google analytics..I am checking it and update you soon.Thanks

Comment: @SRC: you can view the logs at appengine.google.com

Comment: @Wooble:Yes,I checked the logs and corrected the code. But basic question is do django-nonrel supports django signals on GAE since for the login event it is not creating Visitor table (as per my code in models.py.Also same table is creating on development server) ? By the way thanks for pointing me towards appengine logs. I didn't aware about it :-)

Comment: I wonder if no one is aware about it.Friends at least let me know if I am writing my signal codes on proper place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1.

You should not be editing the django framework like you are doing. Don't touch the files inside django.contrib.auth

If you wish to send a signal after someone is logged in, then send the signal in your view where you log the person in

## 2.

Not sure what your actual error is because you are not displaying it (if this is a dev environment set DEBUG = True to get a better stack trace) But by lookingat you code, you are not grabbing the arguments correctly in the signal handler. It should look more like this:

```
def login_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    try:
        user = kwargs['user']
        request = kwargs['request']
        result=Visitor.objects.get(user=user)
        print "You already have login with your name"
    except:
        visitor=Visitor()
        visitor.user=user
        visitor.save()
post_login.connect(login_handler)
```

Comment: Thanks again MattoTodd for your reply..Actually I am not getting any error on the GAE but when I am accessing the values of Visitor table, I am not able to print anything. Its giving me message 'Status: 200 OK Vary: Cookie Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 ' instead of the result. Note that I can see the table is created from Database Viewer on appengine.google.com

Comment: I come to know that this message I am getting due to printing the result before making Http response.So,rendering the template and using result there, giving expected output. By the way I have made certain changes in my code to include signal.send in my views as per your suggestion. Thanks a lot and good wishes!!