# django signal on GAE

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

Does Django signals work on google app engine ? I am using django-nonrel.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine.  Signals do not use the db.

Comment: Thanks MattoTodd for the prompt reply..Actually this question was in relation with the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055608/django-signals-on-gae-with-django-nonrel. I wish if you can guide me on this.

Comment: @SRC - If MattoTodd answered this question for you, would you mind marking it as the answer? Thanks!

Comment: @free-dom:Yes,sure.Thanks a lot guys!!

Answer (score 0):

> Does Django signals work on google app engine ?

Yes, as long as you save those models use the `Model.save()`