# How to check session expiration on close of browser in Django?

Tags: django, session, browser

Here is the scenario I wish to handle in Django application

1. User logs in web application.
2. SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE is set to true.
3. User closes the browser window.

Now how to know receive the session info that session has been killed/Destroyed?

Comment: why you need expired session info ?

Comment: while assigning new session check if session already exists by if request.session._session:

Comment: We have a requirement in our application to manage single session at a time for the user. So, if user access from one browser he should not be able to access from any other way like through another browser window. So, if user close the currently signed in window of browser and tries to log in on another browser window he receive message 'user already log in' . So we need to address this scenario that if user close the browser window session should automatically gets expire from server end also.

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408823/django-how-to-prevent-multiple-users-login-using-the-same-credentials

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you can't know that in Django since it is up to the browser to remove the cookie when session ends (browser is closed). If `SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE` is set to `True`, cookie will not include Expire value, which specifies lifetime of the cookie, and will thus be removed by browser when session ends.