# How do I open a session to keep login credentials through multiple http requests?

Tags: django, angular, get-request

I'm trying to make Http requests using Angular 6. My login call works, but when I try to get use a different call, it tells me I'm not logged in. I think it's because the login isn't valid, but I'm not sure how I can keep it valid for subsequent calls. Here is the code appComponent file:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
     this.data = this.login.getData();
    this.farmAccessdata = this.getFarmAccess.farmAccess();
  }
```

And here is the login service:

```
export class loginService { 
  base_URL = "..."
  login = {
    username: username,
    password: password
  }
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
  }



getData(){
    return this.http.post(this.base_URL + "...", JSON.stringify(this.login))
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log("We got ", data)
    })
  }
```

And the farmaccess service:

```
export class GetFarmAccessService {
  data = {};
  baseURL = "..."
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  farmAccess(){
   return this.http.get(this.baseURL + "...")
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log("We got ", data)
    })
    }
```

When I run the farmAccess service, it gives me an error saying I'm not logged in. The login framework on the server side is cookie based auth, powered by django user module. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: You need to either set a value for the session in your django app or save the session in a cache see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293291/create-a-session-in-django and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/#examples    and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408823/django-how-to-prevent-multiple-users-login-using-the-same-credentials

Comment: @jackotonye I'm going to try token auth by sending an access token in the first call, and sending it as a header in subsequent calls!

Comment: Take a look at https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html to setup oauth2 access tokens