# django session post save called twice

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, session

New to Django Session,
I want to prevent multiple login from same credential.

```
class UserManager(models.Model):
    """
    It hold session_key used for log-in for particular user.
    """

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, db_index=True)
    session = models.OneToOneField(
        Session, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )


def session_post_save(**kwargs):
    session = kwargs['instance']

    uid = session.get_decoded().get('_auth_user_id')

    if uid:
        profile = UserManager.objects.get(user__id=uid)

        # delete old session
        if profile.session:
            profile.session.delete()

        # update session value
        profile.session = session
        profile.save()


post_save.connect(session_post_save, sender=Session,
                  dispatch_uid='session_post_save_add_usermanager')
```

The problem is, I am not able to figure out why session_post_save method getting called twice? or working of session?

First time it get called when user `login()` method exceuted and having `session.get_decoded().get('_auth_user_id')` is None and then Session get **deleted** in some function `django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py(279)cycle_key()`. Don't know why?

Again inserted back.
Second time session_post_save method get called while sending response back, `session.get_decoded().get('_auth_user_id')` is not None.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by preventing multiple login from same credential?

Comment: @LorenzoPeña If same credential used by 2 person in different machine then 1st person should automically be logout.

Comment: It's okay that session is saved multiple times. Make your code idempotent.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another question with some suggestions for IP addresses about how you might make this happen

[detect multiple logins into a Django web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821870/how-can-i-detect-multiple-logins-into-a-django-web-application-from-different-loc)