# Maintaining sessions in Django

Tags: python, django, session

I have the idea that when a user logs in then his session key is stored in django-session table.

Now, how do we prevent a user from logging from one tab and trying to login with another account from another tab, they shouldn't be able to do this.

Comment: Maybe you can try this example: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821870/how-can-i-detect-multiple-logins-into-a-django-web-application-from-different-loc)

Comment: Usually, browser tabs share cookies(and other info) from same origin unless you use something like HTML5 SessionStorage or user has special browser settings/plugins. You can't 100% prevent user from another login. At least you can do is check in your login function if the user is already authenticated(request.user.is_authenticated()) and do not perform login(). More advanced technicues include getting browser fingerprints, collecting user behaviour models, others.