# I am using django-oauth2-provider to generate token. But i want to keep one session at a time

Tags: django, bearer-token, edx, django-oauth

I am using django-oauth2-provider to generate token. But i want to keep one session at a time. Like if a user login at one device and request another login from other device then the initial token should be expired. Can I handle this thing with django-oauth2-privder package

Answer (score 0):

Here's another question with some suggestions about how you might make this happen

[detect multiple logins into a Django web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821870/how-can-i-detect-multiple-logins-into-a-django-web-application-from-different-loc)

Comment: It is possible with many ways. Like i can code myself or use middlewares etc. But i wanted to use oaut2-provider settings for this if there is any.